USA Visa - Other Names?
My partner's name on the passport is listed as A.Jaffar, A stands for Ahmad, but he's always called as Jaffar, and on his professional (work) ID and papers, he's listed as Jaffar, but on official papers he asks from work he's listed as A.Jaffar.
On the D160 Application for the USA Visit visa, they're asking: Have you ever used other names (i.e., maiden, religious, professional, alias, etc.)?
Should he put "Yes" and mention Jaffar?


My partner's name on the passport is listed as A.Jaffar, A stands for Ahmad,
...
Should he put "Yes" and mention Jaffar?

If anything, they will want to know what 'A' stands for.
So write what you have written here: 'A' stands for Ahmad
